# Returning multiple characters in one column from view

Tags: python, django

A team has a name. A player belongs to a team, a player also has a speed and nationality. Result returns the amount of players over a high speed, and if they don't meet the required speed their nationality is recorded.

```
 models 

 team -> name 

 player -> belongsto(foreign key to team),speed, nationality

 Details -> fastspeed, nationality, team( foreign key to team)

 view.py

 speed = 5

 loop through all the players in a team
 if player.speed > 5 
    speed += 1 
 else
    player.nationality
```

Details should return the number of players with a speed over 5 and return the nationalities of all the player in that team.

```
     team number     fastspeed| nationalities
    ---------- --------------  --------------
        1                5        American
                                  French
                                  British
    ----------------------------------------
       2                3         German
                                  Australian
```

Multiple nationalities are being returned per team. Finding out how many fast players is easy we just use an incremental value that we define above. But finding out the nationalities which is a char for every single player in a team seems to be not as easy.

I thought defining a list

```
     nationalitylist = list[] and then doing 

     else nationality = player.nationality
```

then it can be returned by doing details = details()

then this can be passed to details by doing

```
 details = details() 
 details.nationality=nationalitylist
```

struggling to find out how to pass the nationalities of each player per team. I was expecting this to be very easy.

Comment: I found it difficult to understand exactly what you are trying to accomplish. Are you just trying to generate a list of all the nationalities that have a player with a speed of 5 or below?

Comment: Correct :) So I'm finding it difficult to know how to return the multiple nationalities per team to the db.. so the else statement

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm going to take a stab at helping you with this. My understanding of the problem is that you wish to get a list of all the nationalities that have a player with a speed of 5 or below.

First we define an empty list of nationalities and then iterate over all of your players checking if their speed. If their speed is 5 or below we add them to the nationalities list.

```
nationalities = []
if player.speed > 5:
    speed +1
else:
    nationalities.append(player.nationality)
```

This will give us a list of every nationality that has a player with a speed less than 5. However, if there are multiple slow players of the same nationality, then that nationality will appear multiple times in your list.

If you only want that nationality to show up once in your list then we can use the following command to turn the list into a set and then back into a list. This will remove any duplicate entries.

```
nationalities = list(set(nationalities))
```

Storing this list in your database will depend on what version of Django and which database you are using.

If you are using PostgreSQL then you have access to array fields which will allow you to store your list directly. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield)

Otherwise you may want to consider dumping your list to json then you can store it an a CharField or TextField.

```
import json
json_nationalities = json.dumps(nationalities)
```